# send a list to view,fill and get it in asp.net mvc

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, radio-button

I have a quiz form,that it shows some question with it's answers(radio buttons),
the user must answer the questions and send it,
i made some class like this :

```
  public class Question 
{

    public int Qid { get; set; }
    public string Questionstext { get; set; }
    public int selected { get; set; }
    public List<Qitem> lst { get; set; }

}
public class Qitem
{
    public int id { get; set; }
    public string txt { get; set; }

}
```

then i send a list of Question into view :

```
 List<Question> llst = new List<Question>
        {
            new Question
            {
                Qid = 1,
                Questionstext = "is it true?",
                lst = new List<Qitem>
                {
                    new Qitem
                    {
                        txt = "yes",
                        id = 1
                    },
                    new Qitem
                    {
                        id = 2,
                        txt = "no"
                    }
                }
            },
            new Question
            {
                Qid = 1,
                Questionstext = "is it true 2?",
                lst = new List<Qitem>
                {
                    new Qitem
                    {
                        txt = "yes2",
                        id = 3
                    },
                    new Qitem
                    {
                        id = 4,
                        txt = "yes3"
                    }
                }
            }
        };

        return View(llst);
```

how can i show it and then submit the answers,
the answer must be put in 'selected' property of Question.
my problem is about view and Specially radio buttons.

Answer (score 2):

Your view should be

```
@model List<Question>
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    for (int i = 0; i < Model.Count; i++)
    {
        @Html.HiddenFor(m => m[i].Qid)
        <h2>@Model[i].Questionstext</h2>
        foreach (var answer in Model[i].lst)
        {
            <label>
                @Html.RadioButtonFor(m => m[i].selected, answer.id, new { id = "" })
                <span>@answer.txt </span>
            </label>
        } 
    }
    <input type="submit" value="Save" />
}
```

which will post back to (assuming `Index` is the same name as the GET method used to generate this view).

```
public ActionResult Index(List<Question> model)
```

Side note: If you also want the `Questionstext` value to be posted as well, include `@Html.HiddenFor(m => m[i].Questionstext)`

Comment: we can also use Viewbag or tempdata to store the list and use in View if we are sending multiple lists of different models to the view

Comment: @HimaanSingh, `TempData` is not appropriate for sending data to a view, and suggesting `ViewBag` instead on a strongly typed model as OP is doing is awful practive